# SqlConnection DBConnection Windowsce

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, dbconnection, database-connection

I'm writing this piece of code in Compact Framework 3.5 under Windows CE 5.0 to handle two different databases:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Data.Common;

public myClass
{
    private DbConnection dbCn;
    private DbCommand dbCmd;
    public void myClass(bool ce)
    {
        if (ce)
        {
            dbCn = new SqlCeConnection();
            dbCmd = new SqlCeCommand();
        }
        else
        {
            dbCn = new SqlConnection(); // COMPILER ERROR Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection'
            dbCmd = new SqlCommand();// COMPILER ERROR Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' to 'System.Data.Common.DbCommand'  
        }
    }
```

Why it cannot convert SqlXX to DbXX ??? from MSDN SqlXX are children of DbXX! Btw, no problem with SqlCeXX.
I can not use DbPoviderfactory that is missing from cf.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but that did not come out until .NET 4.0.

**[Update]** It appears that casting from [[DbConnection]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to [[SqlConnection]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) could leave out a few parameters, so Microsoft does not allow simple casts.

If you really want to get it done, check out this thread on SO with some good How To code:

[C# DbConnection cast to SqlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3647492/153923)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, SqlConnection inherits from DbConnection, why I can't  write: DbConnection dbCn = new SqlConnection() ???????

Comment: Sorry, now I have understood, the problem is the compiler does not know at compile time what is the right object. Some idea to obtain the desidered result (i.e. something like a DbPoviderfactory)? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, using interfaces, like IDbConnection.

Comment: Sorry. I've been away from the computer. I found a few more details that I posted as an update.