# Closing connection and number of connections to SQL Server DB

Tags: c#

I have a ASP.net application in which I do a query on a SQL Server Database. When the query ends, I do the following :

```
reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
```

And still when I go on SQL Server and does :

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NoOfConnections,
    loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame
```

I can see the 'NoOfConnections' that keeps increasing while I have closed the connection and there is a moment where I'll get an error because I have over 100 connections opened. **How do I close the connections properly**?

Comment: Use the `using`-statement to dispose unmanaged resources. If you dispose/close a connection it is not closing the physical connection. That's up to the [connection-pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx). Closing a connection when connection-pooling is enabled(default) just means that this connection is free to use now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this

```
reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
```

Why not use using statements? Example, for Connection:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
{
    //your code here
}
```

This will close and dispose of the SqlConnection object for you.

Comment: So i finally changed all my treatments to use your solution and it works better.

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server connection pooling will cache connections. You can clear all connection pools with this:

```
conn.ClearAllPools();
```

For more info, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To clear the connection pool for a specific connection, you can use the ClearPool method. For example:

```
conn.ClearPool();
```

For more info, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearpool(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can configure the size of the connection pool through the connection string, for example:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ServerName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Min Pool Size=5; Max Pool Size=20;
```

You can turn off pooling in the connection string also, for example:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ServerName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Pooling=false;
```

Connection Pooling is on by default, the default size of the connection pool is 100. If the client connection string is the same, the pool will try and use a connection from the connection pool - if it is available. For more see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I am using IDbConnection so i can't use these methods, can it works if i cast my IDbConnection to SqlConnection and then call the method "ClearPool" ?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, you should probably use SqlConnection throughout. It is not safe to cast from IDbConnection to Sql Connection - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647492/c-sharp-dbconnection-cast-to-sqlconnection